# What is this different airplane being flown in formation by the Red Arrows

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, flying-in-formation

I was in Lincoln, UK today and saw the Red Arrows practicing.

After looking more closely at the photos I took, I see that one of the formation aircraft is different.

[image: red arrows in formation against blue cloudy sky]

[image: red arrows in formation against blue cloudy sky cropped]

What is this different aircraft? Why are they flying two variants?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's a [Folland Gnat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folland_Gnat) based on the swept wing, thing on the nose and under-wing attachments. They [used to fly it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Arrows#Aircraft) (over 40 years ago). I'm still interested to know why it would be flying today?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @Tim wrote in the comments, it's a [Folland Gnat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folland_Gnat).

The [Red Arrows' own website](https://www.raf.mod.uk/display-teams/red-arrows/news/classic-jet-helps-launch-red-arrows-60th-display-season-calendar/) offers this explanation, in a news release posted on March 8, 2024:

> A vintage jet, of the type used by the original Red Arrows, has flown alongside the present-day team to help mark their 60th display season.
>
> The Folland Gnat, which dates from 1964, joined the Royal Air Force Aerobatic Team’s distinctive BAE Systems Hawks above the skies of Lincolnshire.
>
> Pilots and engineers from yesteryear, as well as Air Cadets representing the future of the RAF, were also at RAF Waddington for the special diamond season celebration.

Comment: Google says it was posted 5 hours ago, so only just before I did my searches!